# 8-element set question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider an $8$-element set $X$ with elements $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8\}$. How many subsets of $X$ contain $x_2$ and $x_3$ but not $x_5$? Please give an arithmetic expression if possible.

Any ideas guys? I have absolutely no clue how to calculate it. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: given any subset of $\{x1,x4,x6,x7,x8\}$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an 8-element set X with elements {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}. How many subsets of X contain x2 and x3 but not x5? Please give an arithmetic expression if possible.

x2 and x3 must be in the set and x5 must not be in our set. This means that x1, x4, x6, x7, and x8 can be either in or out of our set, giving us two possibilities per each of these elements. There are 5 elements with 2 options for each, so by the product rule, the solution is $2^5$.

Comment: what would be the arithmetic function though ?

Comment: $2^5$ = $2 + 2 + ... + 2 + 2$ where you add 2 to itself 16 times.

Comment: So is 2^5 the arithmetic function ? @user112825

Comment: I believe the arithmetic function you are looking for is one of the following: $2^5$, $2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2$, or $2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2$. Whatever it is, it will be equal to 32.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We need to make a subset of $\{x_1,x_4,x_6,x_7,x_8\}$ to keep $x_2$ and $x_3$ company.

Answer (score 1):

For any element except for $x_2,x_3$ and $x_5$ we have to chose if the element is in or not (so that is 5 yes or no choices) By the rule of product there are $2^5=32$ ways to chose.